# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CL/cl.h'

Tags: python-2.7, pyopencl

I read all the solutions provided in this website in order to solve this problem, but it still exits.
When I run this command in cmd in windows 10 `C:\pyopencl-2016.2.1>setup.py install`, this error will be shown:

```
c:\pyopencl-2016.2.1\src\c_wrapper\clinfo_ext.h(10) : fatal error C1083: 

Cannot open include file: 'CL/cl.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Users\\Neda\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Also, there is no `cl.exe` and `CL/` in the paths mentioned above.
I would really appreciate your attention.

EDITED:
I also ran this command in cmd `Command "pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-DHAVE_GL=1" pyopencl` and the problem was the same:

```
c:\users\neda\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ugbqq9\pyopencl\src\c_wrapper\clinfo_ext.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CL/cl.h': No such file or directory
error: command '

C:\\Users\\Neda\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\neda\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\neda\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ugbqq9\\pyopencl\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" build_ext -DHAVE_GL=1 install --record c:\users\neda\appdata\local\temp\pip-l6bnzf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\neda\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\include\site\python2.7\pyopencl" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\neda\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ugbqq9\pyopencl\
```

Answer (score 8):

I have successfully installed pyopencl on a Windows 10 AMD machine. 
For other Windows AMD users, read on.

The AMD APP SDK is now [discontinued by AMD](https://community.amd.com/thread/228114#comment-2860201), however the last release version you can find on Github. I recommend you [install it from here](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/OCL-SDK/releases).

Next, you will need to specify a few command line flags to pass onto the compiler when building. I used:

```
pip3 install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-Ic:\Program Files (x86)\OCL_SDK_Light\include" --global-option="-Lc:\Program Files (x86)\OCL_SDK_Light\lib\x86_64" pyopencl
```

This worked for me, you may have to adjust your `-I` and `-L` arguments according to where the OCL SDK installed to.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! However with python3 and I used CUDA toolkit 10.2.

Comment: Confirmed to work. Win10 x64, AMD RX series GPU, Python 3.9.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked on my device which has a Vega 8 GPU

Comment: For reference, this worked for me with python3 and CUDA toolkit 11.5 

pip3 install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-Ic:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\include" --global-option="-Lc:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\lib\x64" pyopencl

Answer (score 6):

Seems you don't have any OpenCL SDK installed.

There are different SDK from different providers:

- NVIDIA – [CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)
- AMD – [AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/)
- Intel - [OpenCL SDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl)

At first, install OpenCL SDK, and don't forget to setup right environment variable INCLUDE to point to your OpenCL include library (for example: `INCLUDE = C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\6.3\include`).

Comment: I installed cuda nvidia toolkit, I am trying to do pip install pyopencl .. still getting this error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Works fine for me, except that the path is a different one. Here I need to use `set INCLUDE="C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\system_studio_2020\OpenCL\sdk\include/"` and `set LIB="C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\system_studio_2020\OpenCL\sdk\lib\x64\"` (the latter is for finding OpenCL.lib).

Answer (score 0):

I have already installed Intel SDK,  Python 3.7 and Numpy on my Windows 10 with Intel CPU and GPU. Now I wanted to try pyOpenCL. Using this installation method below didn't help:

```
 pip install pyopencl
```

Instead, I followed the info on this [page](http://www.minho-kim.com/courses/17sp43.635/pyopencl.html) and then located the correct version of WHL file needed for my system, and have it installed successfully by running:

```
pip install pyopencl-2019.1.2+cl12-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

And test it like so:

```
import pyopencl as cl
```