# Python PyOpenCL does not work

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pyopencl

Does anybody has a clue, why this command leads to this error?
I am trying to install that on a Windows10 machine with a NVIDIA GPU and CUDA and Python 2.7.14 installed.

The DOS command:

> python -m pip install  pyopencl

The Output / Error:

> Collecting pyopencl   Using cached pyopencl-2017.2.tar.gz Requirement
>   already satisfied: numpy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from
>   pyopencl) Requirement already satisfied: pytools>=2017.2 in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyopencl) Requirement already
>   satisfied: pytest>=2 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyopencl)
>   Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=3.2.0 in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyopencl) Requirement already
>   satisfied: cffi>=1.1.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from
>   pyopencl) Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyopencl) Requirement already
>   satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyopencl)
>   Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.5.0 in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pytest>=2->pyopencl) Requirement
>   already satisfied: attrs>=17.2.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
>   (from pytest>=2->pyopencl) Requirement already satisfied:
>   pluggy<0.7,>=0.5 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from
>   pytest>=2->pyopencl) Requirement already satisfied: funcsigs;
>   python_version < "3.0" in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from
>   pytest>=2->pyopencl) Requirement already satisfied: colorama;
>   sys_platform == "win32" in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from
>   pytest>=2->pyopencl) Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pytest>=2->pyopencl) Requirement
>   already satisfied: pycparser in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from
>   cffi>=1.1.0->pyopencl) Installing collected packages: pyopencl
>   Running setup.py install for pyopencl ... error
>       Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='c:\users\USERA\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6sqhas\pyopencl\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record c:\users\USERA\appdata\local\temp\pip-jcsz8t-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\algorithm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\bitonic_sort.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\bitonic_sort_templates.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\cache.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\capture_call.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\cffi_cl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\clmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\clrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\cltypes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\elementwise.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\invoker.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\ipython_ext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\mempool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\reduction.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\scan.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\tools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl_buffers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl_cluda.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl_mymako.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       copying pyopencl__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\characterize
>       copying pyopencl\characterize\performance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\characterize
>       copying pyopencl\characterize__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\characterize
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\compyte
>       copying pyopencl\compyte\array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\compyte
>       copying pyopencl\compyte\dtypes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\compyte
>       copying pyopencl\compyte__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\compyte
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\compyte\ndarray
>       copying pyopencl\compyte\ndarray\gen_elemwise.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\compyte\ndarray
>       copying pyopencl\compyte\ndarray\gen_reduction.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\compyte\ndarray
>       copying pyopencl\compyte\ndarray\setup_opencl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\compyte\ndarray
>       copying pyopencl\compyte\ndarray\test_gpu_elemwise.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\compyte\ndarray
>       copying pyopencl\compyte\ndarray\test_gpu_ndarray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\compyte\ndarray
>       copying pyopencl\compyte\ndarray__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\compyte\ndarray
>       running egg_info
>       writing requirements to pyopencl.egg-info\requires.txt
>       writing pyopencl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
>       writing top-level names to pyopencl.egg-info\top_level.txt
>       writing dependency_links to pyopencl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
>       warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
>
> ```
> reading manifest file 'pyopencl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
> warning: no files found matching 'src\c_wrapper\*.hpp'
> warning: no files found matching 'doc\_static\*.css'
> warning: no files found matching 'doc\_templates\*.html'
> writing manifest file 'pyopencl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-airy.cl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-bessel-j-complex.cl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-bessel-j.cl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-bessel-y.cl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-complex.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-eval-tbl.cl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-hankel-complex.cl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-ranluxcl.cl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-random123
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-random123\array.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-random123
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-random123\openclfeatures.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-random123
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-random123\philox.cl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-random123
> copying pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-random123\threefry.cl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyopencl\cl\pyopencl-random123
> running build_ext
> generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-2.7\\Release\\pyopencl._cffi.cpp'
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
> building 'pyopencl._cffi' extension
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\build
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\c_wrapper
> C:\Users\USERA\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS-
> ```
>
> /DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pyopencl -DPYGPU_PYOPENCL=1
>   -DPYOPENCL_USE_SHIPPED_EXT=1 -Isrc/c_wrapper/ -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tpbuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pyopencl._cffi.cpp
>   /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pyopencl._cffi.obj -std=gnu++11
>       cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu++11'
>       pyopencl._cffi.cpp
>       C:\Users\USERA\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\stdint.h(82) : error C2371: 'int8_t' :
>   redefinition; different basic types
>               build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pyopencl._cffi.cpp(211) : see declaration of 'int8_t'
>       c:\users\USERA\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6sqhas\pyopencl\src\c_wrapper\clinfo_ext.h(10)
>   : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CL/cl.h': No such file
>   or directory
>       error: command 'C:\Users\USERA\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
>   C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
> ```
>
> tokenize;**file**='c:\users\USERA\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6sqhas\pyopencl\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record c:\users\USERA\appdata\local\temp\pip-jcsz8t-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\USERA\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6sqhas\pyopencl\

Comment: I got it work with the Windows32-bit version of Python 2.7.13.

Comment: I think I had some issues with the Python 2.7 version.  I switched to Python 3 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the log:

```
Cannot open include file: 'CL/cl.h': No such file or directory error
```

tells me the OpenCL headers are missing. You should install an appropriate SDK. Since you have an NVidia, I suggest you look in [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

Answer (score 1):

This answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42881165/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-cl-cl-h/61164573#61164573) may help. Check out my answer there. Basically, the installation is done by installing the correct version of WHL file for your system.

Answer (score 0):

I have been this road with cuda (cupy) opencl (pyopencl) and vulkan (kompute).
There are 4 things to get them work.

- Driver installation read documentation (amd-gpu , nvidia)
- Framework installation without or within SDK , with or without tools (cuda+cuda toolkit,rocm,opencl,vulkan,vulkan-utilities)
- python package - wrapper installation (cupy,pyopencl,kompute)
- avoiding version mismatch and adjusting env variables.

All these have dependencies , environment variables and additions to PATH.
While installing these needs to find each others locations so that gcc or packages or configuration files can link to them.

The most straightforward way is to look at documentation and follow the steps for an OS - for a framework and driver version.

And if something does not work , revert back and correct what it is wrong.

**In your case:**

```
 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CL/cl.h': No such file or directory error: command
```

There seems to be either opencl headers and cpp files or a PATH variable missing.

Second error is :

```
C:\Users\USERA\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\stdint.h(82) : error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pyopencl._cffi.cpp(211) : see declaration of 'int8_t'
```

In visual C++ for python 9.0 in line 82 there is a redefinition of int8_t basic type which is declared and defined first as int8_t  in pyopencl.cffi.cpp which is build temp.

I guess there is an #ifndef int8_t missing not to redefine it ...

As a final advice. Use latest stable versions of OS - driver - framework - python package from an installation guide.

For example I don't know why you use python 2.7 instead of python 3.9+

I am on latest archlinux with python 3.10.2 and everything both AMD and Nvidia both opencl cuda opengl vulkan-compute works ...